# Web Service returns SOAP but properties are empty

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I created a web-service client, compiled a WSDL, everything is OK except empty properties after calling Logon method (ResponseCode, etc. are empty).

I have a response SOAP message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sas="http://ws.test.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sas:LogonResponse>
         <SessionID>19790</SessionID>
         <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
         <ResponseMessage>Logon OK</ResponseMessage>
      </sas:LogonResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The WSDL part for this method looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:sas="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://ws.test.com/" xmlns:ns="http://ws.test.com/" targetNamespace="http://ws.test.com/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <sas:schema xmlns:sas="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://ws.test.com/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <sas:element name="Logon">
                <sas:complexType>
                    <sas:sequence>
                        <sas:element name="Username" type="sas:string" nillable="false"/>
                        <sas:element name="Password" type="sas:string" nillable="false"/>
                    </sas:sequence>
                </sas:complexType>
            </sas:element>
            <sas:element name="LogonResponse">
                <sas:complexType>
                    <sas:sequence>
                        <sas:element name="SessionID" type="sas:long" nillable="false"/>
                        <sas:element name="ResponseCode" type="sas:integer" nillable="false"/>
                        <sas:element name="ResponseMessage" type="sas:string" nillable="false"/>
                    </sas:sequence>
                </sas:complexType>
            </sas:element>
        </sas:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="LogonRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="Logon" element="tns:Logon"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="LogonResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="LogonResponse" element="tns:LogonResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="rrrwebservice">
        <wsdl:operation name="Logon">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:LogonRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:LogonResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="mvcBinding" type="tns:rrrwebservice">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Logon">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://ws.test.com/Logon" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="RRRWebService">
        <wsdl:port name="RRRWebService" binding="tns:mvcBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://172.6.2.14:8008/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Can not figure out the problem.
I compiled it by selecting "Add service reference" in Visual Studio 2008.
Any comments and answers will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, edited the post and corrected the http://ws.test.com namespace. it was changed by hand for security reasons

Comment: Which one exactly is wrong?

Comment: Either. They must be the same.

Comment: Both are "http://ws.test.com/" aren't they?

Comment: My bad. The problem is the _contents_ of the `LogonResponse`. The elements _inside_ it need to be in the `http://ws.test.com/` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The half-assed MS implementation is very picky about the format. It wants the ns:tag notation like here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soap:Body>
            <ns2:SessionCreateResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/">
                <SessionID>3efVfYNzxB2z8wUKQRPeVYc7K9JddAlf</SessionID>
            </ns2:SessionCreateResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I have a response from a app called OTRS which is written in Perl. It created a response like this:

```
    <soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soap:Body>
          <SessionCreateResponse xmlns="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/">
             <SessionID>juFUKqABresNemTCYtPHFiLFWgjJ4QNj</SessionID>
          </SessionCreateResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

MS will not have it. Messing with the XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified/None does nothing. I had to hack in an override in Reference.cs to just reformat the message.

```
    protected override XmlReader GetReaderForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize)
    {
        var newStream = new MemoryStream();
        var orgStream = message.Stream;
        byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
        orgStream.Read(buf, 0, bufferSize);
        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);            
        int pos = response.IndexOf("Response xmlns=");
        if (pos == -1)
        {
            pos = response.IndexOf("Response>");
            if (pos > -1)
                response = response.Insert(pos + 8, " xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"");
        }
        if (pos > -1)
        {
            int pos2 = pos + 8;
            int pos3 = pos + 14;
            while (response[--pos-1] != '<') ;
            string tagName = response.Substring(pos, pos2 - pos);
            response = response.Insert(pos3, ":ns2").Insert(pos, "ns2:");
            int pos4 = response.IndexOf("</" + tagName) + 2;
            response = response.Insert(pos4, "ns2:");
        }
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(newStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.WriteLine(response);
        sw.Flush();
        newStream.Position = 0;
        return new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(newStream);
    }
```